# What is the correct way to count the number of days between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

This question: [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript/15289883#15289883) proposed the following way to calculate the difference between two dates:

```
var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// a and b are javascript Date objects
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}
```

That's correct for some purposes, but not all purposes. Specifically, with day light savings time you could have a 24-hour span that does not pass midnight, which does not count as a full day for medical billing purposes, for example. How do I calculate specifically the number of midnights that occur between two dates in javascript?

Comment: Does this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript) answer your question ?

Comment: If you read the comments on the accepted answer, it actually discusses your daylight savings time issue.